# how to create a gradual increase in height for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code which is not getting any changes in height when I ask it to go for a loop

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var increase = [2,4,8,10];

    for (var i=0; i<=increase.length; i++) {

        $('#cir').height(i);
      }
   });
```

Comment: You mean `$('#cir').height(increase[i]);` ?

Comment: Exactly,,, I want the values of the increase array to be added to the initial height of the DIV

Answer (score 3):

Use [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead:

```
$('#cir').animate({ height: "+=10" });
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onfuqy25/)

Comment: true dear,

But I want the process to loop for once

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean, but `animate()` will only animate once.

Comment: I want the values of the increase array to be added to the initial height of the DIV  .... but thanks any way

Answer (score 0):

Please resolve this issue "*Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"* if you are getting it. If not, then modify your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var increase = [2,4,8,10];

for (var i=0; i<=increase.length; i++) {

    $('#cir').height(i); // this will always give you 4px because you have been using
  }                      // index i value instead of array's index value. it should be 
});                       // $('#cir').height(increase[i]); or if you want to use animation you can use $('#cir').animate({ height: "+=10" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code, to increase your div's height by the one mentioned in the array :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var increase = [2,4,8,10];
    var divctrl = $('#cir');
    var divctrlHeight = divctrl.height();
    for (var i=0; i<=increase.length; i++) {           
       divctrl.height(divctrlHeight + increase[i]);
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   var increase = [2,4,8,10];

   for (var i=0; i<=increase.length; i++) {

      $('#cir').height($('#cir').height() + increase[i]);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the right answer:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var increase = [20,40,80,100,250]

        for (var i=0; i < 12; i++) {

    $('#cir').animate({height: 250 + increase[i]})
    }
    });
```

This gradually increases the size of your div according the value of the array proposed in the for loop :)